# Spring Devtools Live reload in Docker ist not working

Tags: docker, intellij-idea, spring-boot-devtools

I've tried to configure the live reload in spring boot application, using Intellij and Docker, but this is not working.

```
IDE: IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1.2 (Community Edition)
OS: Ubuntu 22.04
Open JDK: 20.0.1
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.coding4world</groupId>
    <artifactId>user-api</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>user-api</name>
    <description>User API</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>20</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludeDevtools>false</excludeDevtools>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

application.properties

```
#local environment configuration
spring.devtools.remote.secret=mysecret
```

dockerfile (I tried to generate the image with spring-boot:build-image too, but it didn't work too)

```
FROM eclipse-temurin:20.0.1_9-jre-alpine@sha256:a0c54e367b648e585722fc6e8d69361ad54bafdc5b89584da987b996b035fb11
WORKDIR /opt/app
RUN addgroup --system javauser && adduser -S -s /usr/sbin/nologin -G javauser javauser
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
RUN chown -R javauser:javauser .
USER javauser
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "app.jar"]
```

[RemoteSpringApplication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCxSP.png)

Error:

```
2023-06-23T20:37:35.011931163Z Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
2023-06-23T20:37:35.011932745Z  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
2023-06-23T20:37:35.011934197Z  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
2023-06-23T20:37:35.011935667Z  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:873) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar!/:na]
2023-06-23T20:37:35.011937223Z  ... 30 common frames omitted
2023-06-23T20:37:35.011938668Z Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
2023-06-23T20:37:35.011940173Z  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:885) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar!/:na]
2023-06-23T20:37:35.011942895Z  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:846) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar!/:na]
2023-06-23T20:37:35.011944542Z  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar!/:na]
2023-06-23T20:37:35.011946041Z  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1328) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar!/:na]
2023-06-23T20:37:35.011947551Z  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1318) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar!/:na]
2023-06-23T20:37:35.011949077Z  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
2023-06-23T20:37:35.011950615Z  at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar!/:na]
2023-06-23T20:37:35.011952166Z  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
2023-06-23T20:37:35.011953988Z  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:866) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar!/:na]
2023-06-23T20:37:35.011955568Z  ... 30 common frames omitted
2023-06-23T20:37:35.011957013Z Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@44d4d992]
2023-06-23T20:37:35.011958596Z  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
2023-06-23T20:37:35.011960077Z  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
2023-06-23T20:37:35.011962845Z  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:873) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar!/:na]
2023-06-23T20:37:35.011964383Z  ... 38 common frames omitted
2023-06-23T20:37:35.011965805Z Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@44d4d992]
2023-06-23T20:37:35.011967334Z  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar!/:na]
2023-06-23T20:37:35.011968872Z  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:139) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar!/:na]
2023-06-23T20:37:35.011970357Z  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:173) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar!/:na]
2023-06-23T20:37:35.011971860Z  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4567) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar!/:na]
2023-06-23T20:37:35.011973421Z  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4700) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar!/:na]
2023-06-23T20:37:35.011974933Z  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar!/:na]
2023-06-23T20:37:35.011976480Z  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1328) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar!/:na]
2023-06-23T20:37:35.011977994Z  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1318) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar!/:na]
2023-06-23T20:37:35.011979522Z  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
2023-06-23T20:37:35.011981295Z  at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar!/:na]
2023-06-23T20:37:35.011982896Z  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
2023-06-23T20:37:35.011985477Z  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:866) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar!/:na]
2023-06-23T20:37:35.011987728Z  ... 38 common frames omitted
2023-06-23T20:37:35.011990058Z Caused by: java.lang.Error: factory already defined
2023-06-23T20:37:35.011992165Z  at java.base/java.net.URL.setURLStreamHandlerFactory(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
2023-06-23T20:37:35.011993665Z  at org.apache.catalina.webresources.TomcatURLStreamHandlerFactory.<init>(TomcatURLStreamHandlerFactory.java:121) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar!/:na]
2023-06-23T20:37:35.011995336Z  at org.apache.catalina.webresources.TomcatURLStreamHandlerFactory.getInstanceInternal(TomcatURLStreamHandlerFactory.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar!/:na]
2023-06-23T20:37:35.011996896Z  at org.apache.catalina.webresources.TomcatURLStreamHandlerFactory.register(TomcatURLStreamHandlerFactory.java:73) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar!/:na]
2023-06-23T20:37:35.011998451Z  at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.registerURLStreamHandlerFactory(StandardRoot.java:699) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar!/:na]
2023-06-23T20:37:35.012001313Z  at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.initInternal(StandardRoot.java:686) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar!/:na]
2023-06-23T20:37:35.012002843Z  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar!/:na]
2023-06-23T20:37:35.012004347Z  ... 48 common frames omitted
```

I was trying to configure reload live of my spring boot application in docker and intellij.